# Winsock2 synchronous IO...waiting for WSASend to "complete" using fWait==TRUE in WSAGetOverlappedResult

Tags: sockets, tcp, io, winsock2

A coworker and I are having a disagreement on what constitutes "completion" of a WSASend overlapped IO request.  He asserts using fWait as TRUE in the WSAGetOverlappedResult call only waits until the message is queued for sending.  He believes waiting for the write/send operation to "complete" only means the message was successfully initiated.  In my opinion that is far from a "completed" message to the other side of the socket...that would simple be a beginning of a send and not a completion.  If the fWait of TRUE does not block until the bytes have been sent and been ACKed (or error returned), then this is far from synchronous...it would in fact be acting the same as asynchronous IO because it's just fire and forget.

I have been maintaining our company's communication library with my understanding of how to do, and what is, "synchronous" IO for decades so I'll be shocked if I'm indeed wrong in my understanding.  But my coworker is a brilliant developer with TONS of TCP/IP experience and is adamant he's right.  Says he even posed this question here on stackoverflow and was told he was right.  I can't imagine how I could be misunderstanding "completion" of a send to mean anything other than the sending of the bytes requested were indeed sent and ACKed.  But I've been wrong before LOL

So...who is right?  What EXACTLY does it mean to wait for a WSASend request to be "complete"?  Simply waiting until the message is queued for sending in the TCP/IP stack...or waiting for all the packets that constitute the message to be both sent and ACKed???  Or is the truth somewhere in-between?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong.

A send request is completed when the *request* is no longer being processed. Once the stack has taken over the operation, the request is no longer being processed and its resources can be used for some other purpose.

If you were right, overlapped I/O would be nearly useless. Who would want to have to wait until the other side ACKed a previous send in its entirety before they could queue any more data to the TCP connection?

How would overlapped I/O be useful if there was no way to determine when the queing process was complete? That's what the application needs to know so it can send another chunk of data.

You would *always* have dead time as the send queue would *always* have to get completely empty before more data could be queued on the sending side. Yuck!

And knowing when the ACK is received is useless anyway. It doesn't mean the application on the other end got the data. So it has no meaning at application layer. Knowing that the send has been queued does have meaning at application layer -- it means you can now queue more data to be sent and be guaranteed that all of the data from the previous send will be passed to the receiver's application layer before any data from the next send. That's what the application needs to know.

A synchronous call to WASSend also completes when the send is queued. An asynchronous operation just means you don't have to wait for whatever you'd wait for in a synchronous operation. So that's another reason your understanding would be quite strange.

Lastly, there is *no* standard or common way to wait for a remote ACK with synchronous operations. So you would have to think that asynchronous operations default to providing a semantic that is not even really available with synchronous ones. That's also pretty strange.

Comment: If a synchronous wsasend only waits to queue the message, how is that anything additional to what asynchronous wsasend does?  Asynchronous send doesn't queue the bytes?  That would be novel...and if you're right, then synchronous io is neither synchronous nor waiting for the send request to "complete" anything at all.

Comment: And if you're right, then synchronous io is neither synchronous nor waiting for the send request to "complete" anything at all except a hope the message gets somewhere,  someday.  In our communications with customers, a lost message is huge. I need to know exactly which message failed.  If any send error isn't known or reported until some arbitrary time later, this is an issue.

Comment: "guaranteed that all of the data...will be passed"...  Ethernet communication is hardly perfect, messages are lost sometimes on our customers networks, so this word guarantee is a poor word unless the low level protocol handles handshakes to confirm receipt of the sent bytes...ie. the io request completed. If an error occurs sending a message, my app log this fact or attempt to resend the lost message, or combine the message with others that have become backlogged.  If never informed of a lost message, I can't know if comms are working unless for msgs that require a reply right?

Comment: In rs232 communications, one must handle ACK and NAKs and checksums yourself because there isn't a protocol like tcpip doing this for you right?  But if confirmation of messages sent isn't done with synchronous io with tcpip then the reliability seems extremely suspect and if any error is communicated, it will be extremely stale and of little use in knowing what failed exactly. At least this has been my understanding for 25 years working with our communications systems.  Logs and error handling in the past has seemed to me to confirm my understanding...

Comment: Guess I'll try to think of a way to test this...Seems like words used like "completed" send actually meant the send completed and not just initiated.  Imagine a "completed " wasread only having half the data...

Comment: @SeanLynes a send operation is "complete" when the OS has agreed to take the data off of your hands so you can reclaim the buffer you used to hold the data. The data will be transmitted in the background at a time of the OS's choosing. There is no guarantee that the data will arrive at the destination. Only that the OS promised to try to deliver it. But it has released you to move on to do other things in the meantime.

Comment: @SeanLynes A read operation is "complete" when the OS has supplied *some* amount of data to your buffer (which may be smaller than what you requested, so yes, it may be partial data) and is ready for you to process that buffer.

Comment: @SeanLynes You seem to be expecting the Winsock API to be adding features to TCP that the protocol does not, and cannot, support. If you need acknowledgements at application level, you need to code them at application level.

Comment: I was simply expecting a "synchronous" operation as the documentation implied.  My testing yesterday confirmed I was indeed wrong to believe waiting for the IO to "complete" meant the send had actually finished...  Synchronous sends do not exist even though all terminology used in all documentation implies it does.  I'm quite amazed...

Comment: @SeanLynes The documentation for WSASend either outright states this behavior or says things that couldn't be right if the behavior was as you thought at least four times. For example, "invoking the completion of a routine or setting of an event object, *when the buffer(s) have been consumed by the transport*".  And "Winsock *may* need to wait for a network event before the call can complete".

Comment: Yes...for the WSASend...clear as day.  But if I pass fWait==TRUE to WSAGetOverlappedResult to wait for my send to "complete" synchronously...this does not occur.  The next sentence after that quote "If the operation does not complete immediately, the final completion status is retrieved through the completion routine or WSAGetOverlappedResult."  Not clear that "final completion status" is simply bytes have been queued to send later.  So I simply object to saying a send operation is "complete" when it's just starting to send.  Imagine a read "completing" if peer has simply queued bytes...nope

Comment: @SeanLynes It says pretty clear that the operation is complete when the buffers are no longer needed by the transport layer. The same is true for a receive -- it's true when the buffers are no longer needed by the transport layer.

Answer (score 1):

David is correct.

WSASend will complete when that data is handed off to the TCPIP stack (buffered at their layer) to be sent whenever the transport will allow. If it's a blocking call, it will wait until it's ready to pend; just like if it's async, the OVERLAPPED I/O will complete once it pends.

Some may ask why is this even necessary? This is behavior is crucial for keeping as much data in-flight over a TCP connection. In order to keep as much data in-flight, a sender should call WSASend until it pends (recall if it's a synchronous WSASend call then that thread will just block until WSASend can complete; if it's asynchronous, the async completion will occur once that WSASend call can pend).

Why would WSASend ever pend, why not just complete immediately? WSASend will only complete once the transport (in kernel) is ready to buffer more data. So looping until WSASend pends will keep that connection flush with enough data to keep the maximum data in-flight.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Also, as stated above to "know" if data was received by the caller, the application's protocol should have its own handshake to convey what information was received correctly by the other side of the TCP or UDP connection.

Comment: Sean: if a send fails because the TCP connection failed in some way, the next recv or send request will immediately fail (since that TCP connection is now broken). It's highly recommended for that reason to always have a recv pended on a TCP connection.

Comment: So in this articles timing diagram...IO starts to IO ends means no IO is taking place? IO should stand tor input and output...not queuing up... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o

Comment: Ok..so if I time sending 10 bytes vs 60k bytes with my SendMessage function doing synchronous io, I should see almost no time difference right?  Takes almost no time to queue a buffer, but should take an additional millisecond or two to break the message into packets, send to other computer, then receive an ack. If my call takes the additional time Wireshark shows the message being processed took, then I'm right but if not. I've misunderstood this all along and all the terms and descriptions about synchronous io make no sense.  I'll let y'all know what I discover tomorrow...

Comment: My testing seems to show I am indeed wrong.  Synchronous behavior does not exist for sending...just receiving.  I see how this is a performance help, but I object to all documentation saying sending fWait of TRUE in WSAGetOverlappedResult will wait until the IO request is "complete".  This word implies much more than just it being queued up.  Well..I'm flabbergasted that my understanding was off...but TCP handles things well enough that it hasn't caused me issues before.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. For both TCP and UDP, verifying that data was successfully received is managed by the application protocol above TCP or UDP. Sorry the text is unclear - part of the challenge with Winsock documentation is that Winsock was designed to a transport-agnostic, protocol-agnostic API. For example, one can connect a "Bluetooth" socket. Though since the API was designed, the 99.999% case is really just TCP or UDP over IP.

Answer (score 1):

My testing seems to show I am indeed wrong.  Synchronous behavior does not exist for sending...just receiving.  I see how this is a performance help, but I object to all documentation saying sending fWait of TRUE in WSAGetOverlappedResult will wait until the IO request is "complete".  This word implies much more than just it being queued up.  Well..I'm flabbergasted that my understanding was off...but TCP handles things well enough that it hasn't caused me issues before.

Thanks for the excellent replies and patience with my frustrated replies.  I'm incredibly disappointed at how all the documentation is written using words that would imply my understanding was right...when all along waiting for IO to "end", "complete", "finish" absolutely does NOT wait.